# Using Powershell to create user in RabbitMQ via API

Tags: api, powershell, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a powershell script that setups user "George" after installing RabbitMQ on a new machine.

I can't figure out why this script doesn't work.

The last step gives me a 404 {"error":"Object Not Found","reason":"\"Not Found\"\n"}

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'guest' -AsPlainText -Force
$credGuest = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('guest', $secpasswd)

$secpasswd2 = ConvertTo-SecureString 'george' -AsPlainText -Force
$credAdmin2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('george', $secpasswd2)


$body = @{
               'password' = 'george'
               'tags' = 'administrator'
           } | ConvertTo-Json

$vhosts1 = ''
$vhosts1 = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/users/george' -credential $credGuest  -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body

write '1:'   $vhosts1

$vhosts2 = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2f/'  -Method get  -credential $credAdmin2

write '2:'  $vhosts2


$body2 = @{
               'username' = 'george'
               'vhost' = '/'
               'configure' = '.*'
               'write' = '.*'
               'read' = '.*'
           } | ConvertTo-Json

write '3:' $body2

$vhosts3 = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2f/george' -credential $credGuest  -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body2

write '4:' $vhosts3
```

I've also tried formatting the last step like this:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/george
```

Same 404 error.

I've tried about 20,000 different ways of sending the command in.  From matching other examples perfectly to trying some abstract art and voodoo magic. While watching the managment tool for RabbitMQ I can see George is created.  And he has an empty vhost.  So the first 3 steps work perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright man, you know that I love you, because I'd never heard of RabbitMQ before tonight.  In the last hour, I've installed it on my Windows machine, and now have used [this awesome guide here to the API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) and kind of learned about how it works.

So, when I run your same process step by step , I see everything happen as you state:

George gets created:
[image]

Since your second step is listing the current permissions of the user running the API call, I next see output of the guest account, which has full perms.  Then onto step 3, which builds the target permissions for George.

```
username  : george
write     : .*
read      : .*
configure : .*
vhost     : /
```

From here, Step 4.  When I run this step manually after the previous step...it works!  However, if I run this too quickly, if I run the whole script at once, I will get a 404 error.  It seems that behind the scenes in RabbitMQ a slight pause is needed for the files to be updated with the new user.  When I deleted the user and tried the whole script again too quickly, I got 404's for every step, pretty much.

However, if I add a little `Start-Sleep 5` to pause 5 seconds...

[image]

The whole process completed.  The key place to add a pause is after Step 1 and it seems to need about four or five seconds.

**Making it pretty**

Now of course, I couldn't stop there, so I decided to add a few more minor pauses to improve output readability and also ensure that each operation completes.  I added some purty looking "OK" messages after the step completes, and then added a finishing confirmation of permissions by doing one last API call for the current user.

Here's the completed output

[image]

**Completed Script**

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'guest' -AsPlainText -Force
$credGuest = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('guest', $secpasswd)

$secpasswd2 = ConvertTo-SecureString 'stephen' -AsPlainText -Force
$credAdmin2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('stephen', $secpasswd2)


$body = @{
               'password' = 'stephen'
               'tags' = 'administrator'
           } | ConvertTo-Json

Write-host "About to create new user $(($body | ConvertFrom-Json).Password)..." -NoNewline
$vhosts1 = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/users/stephen' -credential $credGuest  -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
start-sleep 5 
Write-host "OK" -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400
Write-Host  '1: Results:'   $vhosts1

$body2 = @{
               'username' = 'stephen'
               'vhost' = '/'
               'configure' = '.*'
               'write' = '.*'
               'read' = '.*'
           } | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output "Desired perms for new user $(($body | ConvertFrom-Json).Password)" $body2

Write-host "Setting perms for new user..." -NoNewline

$vhosts3 = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2f/stephen' -credential $credGuest  -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body2
Start-sleep 5
Write-host "OK" -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400
write '4:' $vhosts3

'Retrieiving perms for new user to confirm...'
Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2f/stephen'  -Method get  -credential $credAdmin2
```

*Now I just hope I'll get a chance to use RabbitMQ ever again...*

Comment: I think I just found yet another bug for the Windows 2012 x64 with RabbitMQ.

thank you for verifying my script does in fact work. 

When I tried your script on the Windows 2012 server it errored out in the same 404 way.

I have no doubt this is yet another RabbitMQ + Windows 2012 issue, and not something else.

Comment: And RabbitMQ is an amazing tool.  Really love it to death.

I'm keeping you as 'answer' even though tech the one I found is hte answer.  Cuase I"m using your code now... haha

Answer (score 1):

finally stumpled upon a powershell library someone else wrote for interacting with the RabbitMQ api.

https://github.com/mariuszwojcik/RabbitMQTools/blob/master/en-US/about_UnEsapingDotsAndSlashes.help.txt

I found out that certain versions of powershell replace %2f with the / before sending it to rabbit.  If you use this guys functions found here:

https://github.com/mariuszwojcik/RabbitMQTools

Everything runs beautifully. Really great library he put together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this question.  I love Powershell too, but I used a .bat file to run the native RabbitMQ commands as shown below.  I needed to add a user, a vhost, and hook those two up.  I wanted a script so any new developer could run it.

```
cd /D c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.14\sbin
echo cd completed 
call rabbitmqctl add_user bts mypass
call rabbitmqctl set_user_tags bts administrator 
call rabbitmqctl add_vhost base 
call rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p base bts ".*" ".*" ".*" 

Echo ----List Command to confirm results -------- 
call rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
call rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions bts
```

I suppose you could call these from Powershell too. I guess downside of this is that you have to be on the machine running RabbitMQ.